# How to show pop menu on QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, qt4, contextmenu, qgraphicsview

How to show a pop up menu in Qt while right clicking the QGraphicsView? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` is derived from `QWidget`, so just reimplement `contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event)` to spawn a `QMenu`.  If you want one to appear when right-clicking on `QGraphicsItems` *in* the view, then you will have to reimplement `contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent* event)` in the items.